# Driving Navigation using google maps in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, google-maps-flutter

I am using google maps in my flutter app, I have done drawn paths from one point to another using **[flutter_polyline_points](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_polyline_points)**, Now I  want to get turn by turn navigation as mentioned in this [attached picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXAdZ.jpg), is this possible in flutter, or how I will achieve this

Answer (score 0):

This is Google Map Turn by Turn Navigation View. You can launch it using [Android Intent Plus](https://pub.dev/packages/android_intent_plus) lib

```
    AndroidIntent mapIntent = AndroidIntent(
        action:'action_view',
        package: 'com.google.android.apps.maps',
      data: 'google.navigation:q=$yourDestinationLat,$yourDestinationLng'
    );
    mapIntent.launch();
```

Read more at this [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/android-intents)